# GraphQL schema from a single object JSON file in Gatsby

Tags: graphql-js, gatsby

So I'd like to query a single JSON file which is not an array from Gatsby's GraphQL but I don't really know how to do it.

As far as I understand `gatsby-transformer-json` docs - it only supports loading arrays and have them accessible via `allFileNameJson` schema.

My `gatsby-config` plugins (only the necessary ones for this question):

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
  options: {
    name: 'data',
    path: `${__dirname}/src/data`
  }
},
'gatsby-transformer-json'
```

And then let's say in `src/data` i have a `something.json` file, like this:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

Now I'd like to query the data from `something.json` file, but there is no `somethingJson` schema i can query (tried with Gatsby's GraphiQL).

Could someone point out what am I doing wrong or how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so it is possible to query single-object files as long as they have a parent (folder).

Let's take these parameters:

- `gatsby-source-filesystem` configured to `src/data`
- `test.json` file positioned at `src/data/test.json` with `{ "key": "value" }` content in it

Now as the `test.json` file actually has a parent (`data` folder) - you can query the fields from `test.json` like this:

```
{
  dataJson {
    key
  }
}
```

But putting those directly in your root folder is a bad practice, because when you will store another json file, i.e. `secondtest.json` with `{ "key2": "value2" }` content, and will query it with the same query as above, you will get data only from a single node (not sure if it takes first, or last encountered node),

So, the perfect solution for this case is to have your single-object json files stored in separate folders with just one json per folder.

For example you have some "About Me" data:

1. create a `about` folder in your `src/data`
2. create an `index.json` file with i.e. `{ "name": "John" }`
3. query your data

Like this:

```
{
  aboutJson {
    name
  }
}
```

That's it.