# GraphQL query for a single JSON object in Gatsby

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby

I have the basic Gatsby app created with gatsby cli and I am trying to retrieve static JSON data using the *[gatsby-transformer-json](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-json/)* and *[gatsby-source-filesystem](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/)* plugins from a [StaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/) component.

**My end goal is to render static JSON data, generated by a headless CMS. Updating the JSON should update the GraphQL schema generated by the plugins.**

Following the docs and using the tip, provided in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370196/graphql-schema-from-a-single-object-json-file-in-gatsby), I have set up the following structure.

Testing purpose data looks like this

```
{
  "name": "first",
  "age": 34,
  "test": "test1",
  "children": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "child":"child1"
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "child":"child2"
    }
  ]
}
```

it is located as follows

```
 src/data/test/test.json
```

and my GraphiQL query looks like this

```
{
  testJson {
    name
    age
    children {
      id
      child
    }
  }
}
```

This query currently results in the following

```
 {
      "data": {
        "testJson": {
          "name": "first",
          "age": 34,
          "test": "test1",
          "children": []
        }
      }
    }
```

For some reason I am not able to proceed querying data in a the **children** nested array.

```
"children": []
```

The data exported from the CMS consists of a lot of nested arrays, which I currently cannot access. All I get is the top level empty array.

Am I missing a fundamental concept here or are the plugins struggling to parse a proper GraphQL schema from the given JSON?

I have read the documentation thoroughly and cannot seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`children`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createNode) is used [internally](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/1eb1c39bff0edbf043491fd5da0a785c70c88ef2/packages/gatsby-transformer-json/src/gatsby-node.js#L22) for creating hierarchy between `Node`s.

Just rename `children` to something else and it will be fine:

```
{
    "name": "first",
    "age": 34,
    "test": "test1",
    "foos": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "child": "child1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "child": "child2"
      }
    ]
}
```

Now run the corresponding query:

```
{
  testJson {
    name,
    foos {
      id,
      child
    }
  }
}
```

The result will be as expected:

```
{
  "data": {
    "testJson": {
      "name": "first",
      "foos": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "child": "child1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "child": "child2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mehamasum! It works! 

PS: Did not expect that decent naming will cause me so many problems. :)